# read set from map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std

It's very silly question but somehow I am not able to solve.

I have map who key is string and value is set and I want to iterate through value and print it for example

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> test_map_set

for (auto it_map = test_map_set["test"].begin(); it_mpa != test_map_set["test"].begin(); it_map ++ )
{
  auto it = it_map->second;  ===> Here I am getting error that it has no member second
  then iterate through set 
}
```

My question is how to iterate through set ?

Comment: you are iterating over the set (which is mapped to "test") already, just dereference pointer to get to element of that particular set. if you want to iterate over the map, remove the ["test"], which is what you want probably. Also use .end() in stead of the second .begin()

Comment: Your `it_map` is actually an iterator for the set with `key = "test"`. So of course, the set iterator doesn't have a `second` member (actually second is the member of a pair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `std::string` has no member `second`.

Since you have c++11, you can make life a lot easier:

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> test_map_set

for (std::string& set_element : test_map_set["test"])
{
}
```

For deleting:

```
auto& test = test_map_set["test"];
for (auto it = test.begin(); it!= test.end();)
{
    if (it->length()==5)
        it = test.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

This would delete all strings of 5 characters

Comment: you solution work for me. Just one more question if I delete element from the map will it point to next element automatically

Comment: Update question with your answer

Comment: It's bad ettiquette to completely change a question after you got a helpful answer. It makes the answer look wrong and no one gets credit. Moreover the combination will no longer be useful for others, making me inclined to downvote and vote-to-close as well. **Updated**